# Prague golem as a robot - play on BBC Radio 4

Tags: story-identification, radio-play

I would like to find a radio play I heard maybe 20 years ago - so late 1990s, I think.

It was a deliberate retelling of the story of the Prague golem, but set in a futuristic science-fiction setting and with a robot created to protect the protagonists. I believe that the radio play was part of a double-bill with a telling of the original Prague golem story as well.

I seem to remember that the robot's creator was a woman, and I have a strong memory of an incident with a rose, Perhaps the rose had a thorn that had pricked the scientist, drawing blood and the robot reacting strongly to protect her from it, with the scientist saying something like, "Do not attack the rose! Step away from the rose!".

From searching similar questions it sounds very similar to the story [He, She and It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He,_She_and_It/), though I cannot find any indication that this was made into a BBC radio play, so I wonder if it may be a separate, though similar, retelling.

Comment: Could the other version of the radio play be Leonard Nimoy in "The Mysterious Golem of Prague"? http://www.chabad.org/kids/article_cdo/aid/2166967/jewish/The-Mysterious-Golem-of-Prague.htm

Comment: After a bit more googling, I think I may have found it under the title "Body of Glass" which looks to be the UK title for "He, She and It". It looks like the radio play can be downloaded here: https://archive.org/details/BODYOFGLASSByMargePiercy. I'll listen to it and check whether it is the story I remember.

Comment: If you do find it, feel free to post it as an answer. You can accept it within 48 hours or so.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP comment above, this is possibly "Body of Glass" (UK title) or "He, She and It" (US title), originally broadcast in June 1995. A recording is available [via the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/BODYOFGLASSByMargePiercy).